# Change standard endpoints urls Django Rest Framewrok

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm using viewsets.ModelViewSet and want to replace the standard endpoints URLs
for example:
instead of creating new snippet with the "standard" endpoint
POST {BAST_URL}/snippet/
I want to replace it with "create" URL and disabling the standard
POST {BAST_URL}/snippet/create/

I able to create a new custom create method but not to
* use "create" in the URL -> ERROR: Cannot use the @action decorator on the following methods, as they are existing routes: create
* Disabling Standart URL from creating a snippet

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def create_snippet(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(SnippettViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass an extra argument `url_path` to the `@action` decorator like below

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'], url_path='snippet/create', url_name='snippet_create')
def snippet(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(SnippettViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I also disable the standard create method? POST {BAST_URL}/snippet/

Comment: You can use the `GenericViewSet` and define all the actions by yourself using the `@action` decorator.

Comment: I tried do it and still get the error _Cannot use the @action decorator on the following methods, as they are existing routes: create_

Comment: You can add `url_name` as an argument in the `@action` decorator so that you can use any method name. I've edited the answer, please check.